# paramikoでリモートサーバーのファイルのチェックサムはどのように取得したらよいでしょうか？

Tags: python, python3, ssh, openssh

windowsローカル環境から、サーバーへSTFPを使ってファイルをダウンロードする処理の中で、ダウンロードしたファイルとサーバーにあるファイルが同一であるかチェックしたいと思っています。
そのため、チェック処理を行いたいのですが、どのようにリモートサーバーのファイルのハッシュ値を取得すればいいのかというところで躓いています。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

サーバ側がUNIX系OSであると仮定しますが、サーバ上にある md5sum や sha256sum といったチェックサムを計算してくれるコマンドをsshで実行して結果のテキストを受け取ればよいかと思います。

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("hoge.example.com", username="test", password="testpass")

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('md5sum .bashrc')

for line in stdout:
    print(line.strip('\n'))
ssh.close();
```

ファイル正常転送の確認をしたいならば、ローカルで同様のアルゴリズムにてチェックサムを計算しておいて比較すればよいでしょう。

お試しください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
書きもれましたが、サーバ側はlinuxです。また、ユーザの権限が絞られていて、sftpのみでsshコマンドの実行権限を持たないユーザの場合は、不可能ということでよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 「sftpのみでsshコマンドの実行権限を持たないユーザの場合」というような条件は質問に記載した方がより適切な回答が得られるかと思います。

paramiko の API ( http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/sftp.html )としては SFTPFile#check() というサーバ側でチェックサム計算してくれるをメソッドが存在しています。 ただしこれはSFTPサーバ側でchecksumを計算する拡張機能が実装されている場合にのみ動作するようです。


この機能をサポートしている sftp サーバを見たことがないので、お使いの環境でも動作しないのではないかと思われますが、一度お試しください。もし動作しなければコマンド実行権のないユーザの場合、実現は難しいと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございました。おっしゃる通りでchecksumを計算するサーバというところで躓いておりました。助かりました。